# Refer to a gameobject on start

Tags: c#, unity, gameobject

So I want my script to set the initial position of an object depending on the size of the screen and whatever. How do I refer to the gameobject? I know you can modify stuff like their location if the user clicks on it, but how do I refer to the gameobject right when the program starts?

Also, would it be better to have the object already exist and then move it to the right location on start, or instantiate it in the right location on start? How would I do either of these things?

Answer (score 1):

Attach the script to the object itself and you can manipulate it in the built-in `Start` ([Reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html)). It's similar to the `Update` function except instead of being called every frame it's called when the script begins.

```
public void Start ()
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

There's also the function `Awake` ([Reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html)) which is the same except happens earlier in the initialization chain with the noted difference that in `Awake` not everything may be set up yet. AND `Awake` will run even if the script isn't enabled.

```
public void Awake ()
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.

Additional question: how do I set an object to always be in the bottom right of the screen, regardless of aspect ratio?

Comment: Are you using GUI objects or 3D objects? GUI uses screen space so it's simple math based upon the screen width. 3D objects are relative to the camera so you'll have to do quite a bit more math. This deserves a separate question and many more details as to what you're trying to do and what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference objects within the scene by linking them to the script component in Unity's editor. Either declare the variable as public or use SerializeField so that the variable appears in the Inspector, and then drag an object from the scene onto that variable.

EDIT: Write either this

```
public GameObject object;
```

or this

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject object;
```

at the top of your script. Now the variable 'object' will show up in the Inspector within Unity's editor, and you can drag objects onto that variable.

Comment: I don't understand what this means. I don't know how to declare a variable is public, what linking them to a script component means, or what serializefield means. What variable are you talking about?

Comment: er you don't know how to declare a public variable? Do you know how to program? You ask about scripts and tagged the question C#...

Comment: Thanks for the example in your post, I get it now, thanks.